# Use OData Service Functions To Create Multiple Views of Data, Enforce Authorization

Tags: .net, odata, api-design

I am very new to OData and trying to find a reasonable approach for the following:

Say we've got a BlogPost resource, and a BlogPost has an AuthorId field.  We want to provide a view of the data where an Author can see only BlogPosts which they wrote.  Additionally, a relationship may exist which allows some Authors to view BlogPosts written by some other Authors - a parent child relationship, but through some other entities, not directly.

We have been thinking about defining some functions on the BlogPost resource for these two different views.  So maybe:

```
~/BlogPosts.ForUser(123)  - gets BlogPosts where AuthorId = 123
~/BlogPosts.ForParent(123) - gets BlogPosts where the AuthorId is a child of AuthorId 123
```

I realize we could do some of this (probably all) with some sort of OData filtering etc.  But, in addition to creating a "canned" view of the data, we also want to do some authorization checking to make sure the user has access to the records they're asking for.

What we've come up with seems like a reasonable approach.  Then, we'd like if we could do additional OData $filtering and $selecting etc on the results of the function, and curious if that will work.

Finally, if this will work, will it work with OData v3 as implemented for .NET Web API v2.

So the questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable approach?
2. Can we do normal OData $filtering etc on the function results?
3. Is this possible in OData v3, specifically?

**UPDATE**

We've answered the second question.  Yes, you can do OData filtering on the function results.  We've only been successful with v4, and the question of "fit" for this approach still remains.

Answer (score 1):

We've been doing a lot of thinking about the same sort of questions recently, so I'll throw an answer in here, though of course, the answer to "Is this a reasonable approach?" is bound really to be "Yes, if it suits your purpose"...

What we've been leaning towards is that OData becomes something of a read only view on the data that we want to expose to 3rd party consumers.  And we try to keep the OData model structure separate from the internal domain model structure, be that via SQL views, or even via having completely separate OData tables, which are filled when events are raised from our domain entities, a-la DDD + CQRS.

OData seems to be extremely powerful as a read view on the data.  All the filtering, sorting, aggregation etc etc that you get for FREE is pretty compelling.  And there are already tools cropping up which allow you to point a viewer at an OData source and trawl through the data - great when your customer wants a report based on X/Y/Z - build a spreadsheet with an OData data source, and they can now do whatever sculpting they want!

When it comes to authentication/authorization, you can add the standard authorization attributes to endpoints, and then you can also do things like filter the entities which are served - we do this in a "roundabout" (I don't want to say "hack"...) way within the serializer.  This allows us to do things like "OK, get me the list of authors.  Now, which of these authors does this user have access to?  Throw the rest away.  Or, don't throw them away, but instead of serializing the entire object, just serialize the id and the name, not the email address and the phone number".  Seems to be working pretty well.

The filtering and the expansion features of OData are worth the ticket price alone if you ask me.  I don't have any experience of using functions, but again, what I like about it is its flexibility, so I wouldn't really see much need to guide consumers towards one view of the data or another.  Let them do it themselves (unless of course your consumer is YOU, in which case, go for your life...)